# How to get array with images in Angular Modal Gallery

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, gallery

I'm trying to make image gallery in angular app using 'angular-modal-gallery'. The problem is that I don't know how to convert observable(with image data) from media service to array. Angular-modal-gallery docs say that I need to initialize array with my images.

media.service.ts

```
export class MediaService {

  API_URL = AppConfig.settings.api.url;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAlbum = (id: string) => {
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}/album?id=${id}`);
  };
}
```

component.html

```
<modal-gallery [modalImages]="imagesArraySubscribed"></modal-gallery>
```

component.ts

```
export class PhotoComponent implements OnInit {

  imagesArraySubscribed: Array<Image>;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  private album_id = '12121564564564';
  private album$: Observable<any>;

  constructor( private mediaService: MediaService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.album$ = this.mediaService.getAlbum(this.album_id).pipe(map(res => 
  res['photoset']['photo']));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.mediaService.getAlbum(this.album_id).pipe(map(res => 
   res['photoset']['photo'])).subscribe(res => {
      imagesArraySubscribed.push(res)});
```

You should subscribe to the service and push the images that you'll get from the observable to array

Answer (score 0):

You must subscribe to getAlbum method and you will receive the data.

```
this.album$ = this.mediaService.getAlbum(this.album_id).suscribe( (res:any[]) => {
    this.imagesArraySubscribed = res['photoset']['photo']; 
}
```